# How can I simplify this jQuery code

Tags: jquery, function

I want to find a way to make a function from my code. I ll have more than 20 queries like this. It's time to make a function. :)

Thanks.

```
$('#update-user-info').submit(function(msg) {  
    $.post("assets/php/ajax/update-user-info.php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
        if(data=="y") { $('.text-success').addClass('show').removeClass('hide'); }
        if(data=="n") { $('.text-danger').addClass('show').removeClass('hide'); }
    });
    return false;
}); 

// To update user settings
$('#update-user-settings').submit(function(msg) {  
    $.post("assets/php/ajax/update-user-settings.php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
        if(data=="y") { $('.text-success').addClass('show').removeClass('hide').hide(1000); }
        if(data=="n") { $('.text-danger').addClass('show').removeClass('hide'); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `$('#update-user-info, #update-user-settings')`. There is a site [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for questions like this.

Comment: Thanks. It does not answer question for $.post() address.

Comment: @user3396984 please post question on site provided by Danny

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
function baz(response) {
    var node = data === 'y' ? '.text-sucess' : '.text-danger';
    $(node).addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
}

function bar(msg) {
    $.post(url, $(this).serialize(), baz);
}

$('.foo').submit(bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
$('#update-user-info, #update-user-settings').submit(function(msg) {  
    $.post("assets/php/ajax/"+this.id+".php", $(this).serialize(),function(data){
        if(data=="y") { $('.text-success').addClass('show').removeClass('hide'); }
        if(data=="n") { $('.text-danger').addClass('show').removeClass('hide'); }
    });
    return false;
});
```